# RealityKit – Material's Alpha transparency

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Is it possible to have alpha transparency with textures?

I have png file that contains 8 bit RGBA, but for some reason, the supposed-to-be-transparent parts are simply black.

I assign the material like this:

```
private func setupLightMeshes(_ scene: Entity) {
    let lightEntity = scene.findEntity(named: "LightWindow_Plane")!
    var lightMaterial = UnlitMaterial()
    
    lightMaterial.baseColor = try! MaterialColorParameter.texture(
    TextureResource.load(named: "light.png")) // this is 8bpc RGBA
    var modelComponent = lightEntity.components[ModelComponent] as! ModelComponent
    modelComponent = ModelComponent(mesh: modelComponent.mesh, materials: [lightMaterial])
    lightEntity.components.set(modelComponent)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### iOS RealityKit 1.0

`.tintColor` is a multiplier for `.baseColor`

If you have a `.png` file with a premultiplied alpha (`RGB`*`A`). all you need to do is to additionally use a `tintColor` instance property with alpha equal to `0.9999`.

```
material.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.9999)
```

Here's how it looks like in a real code:

```
fileprivate func material() -> UnlitMaterial {

    var material = UnlitMaterial()
    material.baseColor = try! .texture(.load(named: "transparent.png"))
    material.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.9999)
    return material
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let sphere: MeshResource = .generateSphere(radius: 0.5)

    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: sphere,
                        materials: [material()])

    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    anchor.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi, axis: [0, 1, 0])

    anchor.addChild(entity)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
}
```

Seems like a bug in RealityKit for iOS – why `png` transparency doesn't work as expected?!

#### iOS RealityKit 2.0

The same story about partially transparent textures is in RealityKit 2.0:

```
var material = SimpleMaterial()

material.color = try! .init(tint: .white.withAlphaComponent(0.9999),
                         texture: .init(.load(named: "semi.png", in: nil)))
```

`tint` parameter is a multiplier for `texture` as well.

#### RealityKit for visionOS

In visionOS app, to create a transparent material has become easier with `OpacityComponent`:

```
modelEntity.components[OpacityComponent.self] = .init(opacity: 0.25)
```

Comment: It works really well, I setup it wrong at the beginning. It sounds like a hack, so it's possible that nicer solution will be to create a custom material with a specific surface shader

Answer (score 1):

In case of using the **PhysicallyBasedMaterial**, the tint color does not work. You need to use the `blending` property together with `opacityThreshold`.

**RealityKit 2.0**

The easy solution is to use the convenience method to create a transparent texture with an opacity near to 1.

Besides if you want to show the texture for both sides of the mesh which was my case, you can set the `faceCulling` to `none`

```
var material = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
material.baseColor = .init(texture: .init(myPNGTexture))
material.blending = .init(blending: .transparent(opacity: 0.9999))
material.opacityThreshold = 0.0 // IMPORTANT
material.faceCulling = .none
```